# How to find coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

By using intersections command I was able to make effect the line `$\mathcal{P}_{t_{1},\gamma}$`  is dotted outside of the set. However, I am curious if I can take a certain point on this line, for example middle point from an inside part of the line?

From math we know that if we have points `$(x_{1},y_{1})$` and `$(x_{2},y_{2})$`, then the point on the line, which goes on them, has the form `$(\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda)x_{2},\lambda y_{1}+(1-\lambda)y_{2})$`.

In this case `$(x_{1},y_{1})$` and `$(x_{2},y_{2})$` are intersections `(po1)` and `(po2)` (in the code). How can we find any point on the `(po1) -- (po2)` line and connect it to `(7.23,8)`  with the new line?

In any point I mean to parametrize it like we did in second paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5pt]
\draw[line width=0.5pt,name path=cur] plot [smooth cycle] 
    coordinates{(0.43,8.8)  (1.23,9.4)  (2.03,9.4)
                (3.03,9.3)  (4.03,9.5)  (5.43,8.4)
                (4.83,6)    (7.36,6.27) (8.43,6.27)
                (9.43,4.2)  (8.63,2.6)  (5.63,1)
                (4.23,2.6)  (1.23,6)};
\draw[dashed,line width=0.3pt,name path=lin1] (0,10.6)--(9.5,0.5);
\draw[dashed,line width=0.3pt,name path=lin2] (2,10.6)--(11.5,0.5);
\path [name intersections={of={lin1 and cur}, total=\n}]  
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {(intersection-\i) coordinate(po\i)};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (po1)--(po2);
\path [name intersections={of={lin2 and cur}, total=\n}]  
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {(intersection-\i) coordinate(po\i)};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (po1)--(po2);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (po3)--(po4);
\draw (6.2,4) node[below left] {$E_{t_{1},\gamma}$};
\draw[->,line width=0.5pt] (7.23,8)--(8.83,9.6);
\draw (8.03,8.8) node[below right] {$\gamma$};
\draw (7,1) node[below right] {$\mathcal{P}_{t_{1},\gamma}$};
\draw (13,1) node[above left] {$\mathcal{P}_{t_{2},\gamma}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding

```
\path (po1) -- (po2) coordinate[pos=0.90] (btw1a2);
\draw[orange] (btw1a2) -- (7.23,8);
```

at the end of the picture.

You can change `pos=<position>` to any value between `0` and `1` to get the desired point.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Library `calc` is already loaded, then the middle (or any point) between `(po1)` and `(po2)` is easy:

```
($(po1)!0.5!(po2)$)
```

Points between `(po1)` and `(po2)` are specified by a number between 0 and 1. 0 means the first point and 1 the second point. Also negative values or values greater than 1 can be specified to get points outside on the line, defined by `(po1)` and `(po2)`.